# How to connect to redistogo? How to see the data?

Tags: redis, redistogo

Read through https://redistogo.com/documentation/introduction_to_redis?language=en but couldn't get it to work.

```
redis-cli -h my-host -p 1234 -a mypassword
```

What is `my-host`?

How to see the database?

The web console seems to not display all the data. `keys` fails.

redis-cli -h returns "Could not connect to Redis"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On https://redistogo.com/heroku/resources/934839 where your app installs redistogo.

The following link is given:-

```
redis://redistogo:12340994131cb8c2f2402ffdsafds3333129@birdeye.redistogo.com:3244/
```

using this you type on console:-

```
redis-cli -h my-host -p 1234 -a mypassword
redis-cli -h birdeye.redistogo.com -p 3244 -a 12340994131cb8c2f2402ffdsafds3333129
```

and you will log onto console.

Comment: Thanks. Be great if this was in the RedisToGo docs or even a link right off the Heroku add-on general screen.

Comment: nnected> not connected> not connected> not connected> not connected> not connected> appears in the command line

Answer (score 0):

"My-host" is the hostname you get from Redis To Go.